# Override Getter value in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

Please look into the below plunker 
 https://plnkr.co/edit/tYgghDzD521YilSeYyVo?p=preview

We have two input ValA and ValB. ValC will be derive from two inputs(valA and valB). valD we get by multiplying valC * 2.
Eg.

```
valA = 2
valB = 3
valC = 5
valD = 10
```

I want to override ValC. it should take what we input in valC and return respective valD

Eg.

```
valA = 2
valB = 3
valC = 7
valD = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app.ts as follows:

```
C:<input #valC type="text" name="valC" [(ngModel)]= mycal.valC ><br>

D:<input type="text" name="valD" disabled="disabled" value= "{{valC.value * 2}}" ><br>
```

Herein, I am using a template reference variable with C and using its value to populate D.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model.ts file like this

```
export class myCal {
  valA:number;
  valB:number;
  valC:number;

  get valD(){
    return parseInt(this.valC) * parseInt(2);
  }

  constructor(){
    this.valA= 2;
    this.valB= 3;
    this.valC = parseInt(this.valA) + parseInt(this.valB);
  }
}
```